# ¿Como sacar el numero mas grande de un metodo en java?

Tags: java

Tengo que crear un sistema que pueda calcular la temperatura del mar de acuerdo al mes, usando un mes inicial, temperatura inicial, y el mes del cual quiero saber la temperatura de referencia. En ciertos meses la temperatura sube y en otros baja un porcentaje específico. Adicionalmente tengo que hacer que me diga el mes con la temperatura mayor de todos los meses calculados. (Ejemplo: Mi mes inicial es febrero y quiero saber la temperatura en junio, la respuesta seria el numero del mes con mayor temperatura de estos, por ejemplo mayo, que sería el mes 5) El sistema para calcular la temperatura esta hecho pero necesito ayuda escribiendo el metodo par sacar el mes con la temperatura mas alta.

```
package fenomenoninio;

import java.util.Scanner;


/**
 *
 * @author erodriguez
*/
public class FenomenoNinio {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */

//Declaración variables
public int mesActual ;
public int mesProyectado ;
public double temperaturaActual;
public double temperaturaProyectada;


/*Método en la cual vamos a calcular la temperatura proyectada
Se ingresa como datos de entrada el mes actual, el mes proyectado y la temperatura
actual.
nueva_temperatura(1, 12, 25.0)

La respuesta será la nueva temperatura
*/

public double nueva_temperatura(int mesActual, 
        int mesProyectado, double temperaturaActual)
{

    if (mesActual >=1 && mesActual<=12 && mesProyectado >=1 && mesProyectado<=12
            && mesActual <= mesProyectado)
    {
        for (int i=mesActual; i<=mesProyectado ; i++)
        {
            //temperaturaActual = temperaturaProyectada;
            if (mesActual == 1 || mesActual == 4 || mesActual == 7 
                    || mesActual == 10)
            {

                temperaturaProyectada = temperaturaActual + temperaturaActual*0.15;
                //temperaturaActual = temperaturaProyectada;
                //continue;
            }

            else if (mesActual == 2 || mesActual == 3 || mesActual ==11 
                    || mesActual == 6)
            {
                temperaturaProyectada = temperaturaActual - temperaturaActual*0.13;
                //temperaturaActual = temperaturaProyectada;
                //continue;
            }

            else if (mesActual == 8 || mesActual == 9 || mesActual ==5 
                    || mesActual == 12)
            {
                temperaturaProyectada = temperaturaActual + temperaturaActual*0.12;
                //temperaturaActual = temperaturaProyectada;
                //continue;
            }


        }
        System.out.println("La temperatura Proyectada es : "
    + temperaturaProyectada);

    }

    else 
    {
        System.out.println("Ingresar un valor entre 1 y 12");
    }

    return temperaturaProyectada;

}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    FenomenoNinio fenomeno = new FenomenoNinio();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Ingresar el mes actual : ");
    try {
        fenomeno.mesActual= sc.nextInt();
        Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Ingresa la temperatura actual : ");
        fenomeno.temperaturaActual = sc1.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Ingresa el mes a proyectar : ");
        fenomeno.mesProyectado =sc1.nextInt();
        fenomeno.nueva_temperatura(fenomeno.mesActual, 
                fenomeno.mesProyectado, 
            fenomeno.temperaturaActual); 


    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Por favor debe ingresar un valor válido");
    }






    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que el algoritmo correcto para proyectar la temperatura es:

```java
public boolean nueva_temperatura()
{
    float[] variacion = {    0f, 1.15f,  .87f,  .87f, 1.15f,
                                 1.12f,  .87f, 1.15f, 1.12f,
                                 1.12f, 1.15f,  .87f, 1.12f    };

    float    tem = medicionActual.Temperatura,    // ¨\      Estas variables
             min = tem,                           //   \    no son
             max = 0;                             //    |_  necesarias pero
                                                  //    |   ayudan a una
    int      mesMin = medicionActual.Mes,         //   /    mejor
             mesMax = 0;                          // _/      visualización.


    if (medicionActual.Mes <= medicionProyectada.Mes)
    {
        for (int mes = medicionActual.Mes + 1; mes <= medicionProyectada.Mes; mes++)
        {
            tem *= variacion[mes];

            if (tem > max)
            {
                max = tem;
                mesMax = mes;
            }

            if (tem < min)
            {
                min = tem;
                mesMin = mes;
            }
        }

        medicionProyectada.Temperatura = tem;
        medicionMaxima.Temperatura = max;
        medicionMinima.Temperatura = min;
        medicionMaxima.Mes = mesMax;
        medicionMinima.Mes = mesMin;

        return true;
    }       
    else 
    {
        System.out.println("El mes actual debe ser menor que el mes a proyectar.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

### Explicación:

La función `nueva_temperatura` es de tipo `boolean` porque debe retornar `true` cuando pueda realizar la proyección, y `false` cuando no pueda hacerla. Esto resulta útil para la construcción de un bucle que controle que el usuario coloque los datos correctos:

```java
do
{
    fenomeno.medicionActual.Mes         = inputInt("Ingresar el mes actual: ", 1, 12);
    fenomeno.medicionActual.Temperatura = inputFloat("Ingresa la temperatura actual: ");
    fenomeno.medicionProyectada.Mes     = inputInt("Ingresa el mes a proyectar: ", 1, 12);

}while( !fenomeno.nueva_temperatura() );
```

`nueva_temperatura` no recibe parámetros porque forma parte de la clase `fenomenoNinio`, y las variables sobre las que actúa son miembros de dicha clase:

```java
class FenomenoNinio
{       
    Medicion medicionActual;
    Medicion medicionProyectada;
    Medicion medicionMaxima;
    Medicion medicionMinima;

    public FenomenoNinio()
    {
        medicionActual     = new Medicion();
        medicionProyectada = new Medicion();
        medicionMaxima     = new Medicion();
        medicionMinima     = new Medicion();
    }
    // Aquí iría la función nueva_temperatura().
}
```

La clase `Medicion` sirve para registrar la temperatura según el mes:

```java
class Medicion
{
    int Mes;
    float Temperatura;
}
```

Esta estructuración facilita el reporte de las temperaturas junto con los meses respectivos:

```java
System.out.format("El mes actual es: \t %10s \t Temperatura = %5.2f ºC\n",
                  meses[fenomeno.medicionActual.Mes], fenomeno.medicionActual.Temperatura);
System.out.format("El mes proyectado es: \t %10s \t Temperatura = %5.2f ºC\n",
                  meses[fenomeno.medicionProyectada.Mes],
                  fenomeno.medicionProyectada.Temperatura);
System.out.println();
System.out.format("Temperatura mínima = %5.2f ºC \t en el mes %s\n",
                  fenomeno.medicionMinima.Temperatura, meses[fenomeno.medicionMinima.Mes]);
System.out.format("Temperatura máxima = %5.2f ºC \t en el mes %s\n",
                  fenomeno.medicionMaxima.Temperatura, meses[fenomeno.medicionMaxima.Mes]);
```

El vector `meses` se basa en el mismo truco que el vector `variacion`, pero en este caso permite mostrar el nombre de los meses:

```java
/* Permite hacer un reporte más amigable para el usuario,
   mostrando el nombre del mes y no sólo el número. */
static String[] meses = {"", "enero", "febrero", "marzo", "abril", "mayo", "junio", "julio",
                             "agosto", "septiembre", "octubre", "noviembre", "diciembre"};
```

Dentro de la función `nueva_temperatura` encontramos el vector `variacion`:

```java
    float[] variacion = {    0f, 1.15f,  .87f,  .87f, 1.15f,
                                 1.12f,  .87f, 1.15f, 1.12f,
                                 1.12f, 1.15f,  .87f, 1.12f    };
```

El tipo `float` me parece más adecuado que `double` para representar temperaturas, porque tiene una precisión de 3 a 6 cifras significativas en la parte fraccionaria.

Este vector almacena los porcentajes de variación de la temperatura según los meses. Las posiciones 1 a 12 del vector corresponden a los meses, por eso en la posición cero se establece el valor `0f`, lo que permite que la proyección pueda calcularse en una simple línea de código:

```java
tem *= variacion[mes];
```

Para eso se debe verificar una condición:

```java
if (medicionActual.Mes <= medicionProyectada.Mes)
```

Las otras condiciones fueron delegadas en una función que se encarga de que los datos sean correctos en el momento de solicitarlos al usuario:

```java
static int inputInt(String solicitud, int menor, int mayor)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int r = 0;

    do    // De este bucle no se sale hasta que el usuario coloque un
    {     //  número y que además sea válido.
        System.out.print(solicitud);

        if ( sc.hasNextInt() )
            r = sc.nextInt();
        else                // Cuando ingresa por aquí es porque
        {                   // el usuario no colocó un número.
            sc.next();
            System.out.println("Por favor, debe ingresar un número.");
            continue;
        }

        if (r < menor || r > mayor)
            System.out.format("Por favor, el número debe estar dentro del rango [%d..%d].\n",
                              menor, mayor);

    } while (r < menor || r > mayor);

    return r;
}
```

La función `inputInt` devuelve el número entero solicitado al usuario, controlando los errores que éste pudiera cometer. A tal fin los parámetros `menor` y `mayor` permiten controlar que el número esté dentro del rango de los meses.

**[Código completo](http://www.browxy.com/SavedCode/95288)**